# how to add two installation types inside single setup file in installscript

Tags: c#, .net, installshield, installscript

I am using InstallShield 2013 for deployment packages and I want to add two installation types(two applications) in single setup file. I mean , the user should be able to select which application is to be installed when running the setup file at the installShield.

**Background**

In my setup file there are two applications as Console and Viewer. The user can select the application he/she wants but further installation for the selected application does not work. Need help!

**Here is my code.**

```
function OnFirstUIBefore()
      NUMBER nResult, nType;   
      STRING szTitle, szMsg, svResult, szCaption;   
      NUMBER nSetupType, nvSize, nUser, nReserved;
      STRING szQuestion, svName, svCompany, szFile, szLicense;
      STRING szLicenseFile,szReserved, svSetupType;
      LIST list, listStartCopy;
      BOOL bCustom, bCopy, bDontCopy;

begin           
      MessageBox("OnFirstUIBefore()",0);
      SHELL_OBJECT_FOLDER = @PRODUCT_NAME;     
      nSetupType = CUSTOM;     
      bCopy = FALSE ; 
      bDontCopy = TRUE ; 
      bCustom = TRUE;      
      szLicense = SUPPORTDIR^ "AbcTerms.rtf";   

Dlg_SdWelcome:
    szTitle = "";
    szMsg   = "";
    nResult = SdWelcome(szTitle, szMsg);
    if (nResult = BACK) goto Dlg_SdWelcome; 
    szTitle   = "";
    svName    = "";
    svCompany = "";   

Dlg_SdLicense:            
   nResult = SdLicense2Rtf ( "","" , "", szLicense , FALSE );    
   if(nResult = BACK) goto  Dlg_SdWelcome;

Dlg_SdCustomerInformation:
    nResult = SdCustomerInformation(szTitle, svName, svCompany, nUser);
    if (nResult = BACK) goto Dlg_SdLicense;

Dlg_SetupType:            
    szTitle = "Please select installation type"; 
    szMsg = ""; 
    szReserved  = ""; 
    svSetupType = "Viewer"; 
    nReserved   = 0;  

    nResult = SdSetupTypeEx(szTitle, szMsg, szReserved, svSetupType, nReserved);
    INSTALLTYPE =  svSetupType;   //"Console";//  
    if(svSetupType == "Console") then  
         MsiSetProperty( ISMSI_HANDLE, "DOCUSTOMEACTION" , 'copy' ); 
         MsiSetProperty( ISMSI_HANDLE, "INSTALLMODE" ,  "ConsoleV3");//"1:3"           
    else
         MsiSetProperty( ISMSI_HANDLE, "INSTALLMODE" , "ViewerV3" );     //"1:2"        
    endif;
    MsiSetProperty( ISMSI_HANDLE, "SOURCEPATH" , SourceDir ); 
    if (nResult = BACK) goto Dlg_SdCustomerInformation; 

Dlg_SdAskDestPath:      
    nResult = SdAskDestPath(szTitle, szMsg, INSTALLDIR, 0);
    if (nResult = BACK) goto Dlg_SetupType;     
Enable(STATUSEX);
    return 0; end;
```

**Edited Code**

```
function OnFirstUIBefore()
      NUMBER nResult, nType;   
      STRING szTitle, szMsg, svResult, szCaption;   
      NUMBER nSetupType, nvSize, nUser, nReserved;
      STRING szQuestion, svName, svCompany, szFile, szLicense;
      STRING szLicenseFile,szReserved, svSetupType;
      LIST list, listStartCopy;
      BOOL bCustom, bCopy, bDontCopy;

begin           
      MessageBox("OnFirstUIBefore()",0);
      SHELL_OBJECT_FOLDER = @PRODUCT_NAME;     
      nSetupType = CUSTOM;     
      bCopy = FALSE ; 
      bDontCopy = TRUE ; 
      bCustom = TRUE;      
      szLicense = SUPPORTDIR^ "AbcTerms.rtf";   

Dlg_SdWelcome:
    szTitle = "";
    szMsg   = "";
    nResult = SdWelcome(szTitle, szMsg);
    if (nResult = BACK) goto Dlg_SdWelcome; 
    szTitle   = "";
    svName    = "";
    svCompany = "";   

Dlg_SdLicense:            
   nResult = SdLicense2Rtf ( "","" , "", szLicense , FALSE );    
   if(nResult = BACK) goto  Dlg_SdWelcome;

Dlg_SdCustomerInformation:
    nResult = SdCustomerInformation(szTitle, svName, svCompany, nUser);
    if (nResult = BACK) goto Dlg_SdLicense;

Dlg_SetupType:            
    szTitle = "Please select installation type"; 
    szMsg = ""; 
    szReserved  = ""; 
    svSetupType = "Viewer"; 
    nReserved   = 0;  

    nResult = SdSetupTypeEx(szTitle, szMsg, szReserved, svSetupType, nReserved);
    INSTALLTYPE =  svSetupType;   //"Console";// 

    MsiSetProperty( ISMSI_HANDLE, "DOCUSTOMEACTION" , 'copy' );

    if(svSetupType == "Console") then  

         MsiSetProperty( ISMSI_HANDLE, "INSTALLMODE" ,  "ConsoleV3");//"1:3"           
    else
         MsiSetProperty( ISMSI_HANDLE, "INSTALLMODE" , "ViewerV3" );     //"1:2"        
    endif;
    MsiSetProperty( ISMSI_HANDLE, "SOURCEPATH" , SourceDir ); 
    if (nResult = BACK) goto Dlg_SdCustomerInformation; 

Dlg_SdAskDestPath:      
    nResult = SdAskDestPath(szTitle, szMsg, INSTALLDIR, 0);
    if (nResult = BACK) goto Dlg_SetupType;     
Enable(STATUSEX);
    return 0; end;
```

Comment: To understand want you want to do, I have some questions: Your project is of type InstallScript MSI, right? Want do you expect as result from you InstallShield project? msi package or InstallShield Setup.exe? What are your two packages? msi files?

Comment: This is an InstallShield Setup.exe project. It includes InstallScript part even. There are two Setup Designs as Viewer and Console. The user should be able to select the expected application(Setup Design) and the installation process should go in order to that.

Comment: @LucasF , The Edited Code works fine.

Comment: Good for you. The console mode worked also with the old code? So you had to do `MsiSetProperty( ISMSI_HANDLE, "DOCUSTOMEACTION" , 'copy' );` for both INSTALLMODEs.

Comment: Yes. If there are more than one setup types then MsiSetProperty( ISMSI_HANDLE, "DOCUSTOMEACTION" , 'copy' ); should run first. Then further installation for any setup type is working very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine.

```
function OnFirstUIBefore()
      NUMBER nResult, nType;   
      STRING szTitle, szMsg, svResult, szCaption;   
      NUMBER nSetupType, nvSize, nUser, nReserved;
      STRING szQuestion, svName, svCompany, szFile, szLicense;
      STRING szLicenseFile,szReserved, svSetupType;
      LIST list, listStartCopy;
      BOOL bCustom, bCopy, bDontCopy;

begin           
      MessageBox("OnFirstUIBefore()",0);
      SHELL_OBJECT_FOLDER = @PRODUCT_NAME;     
      nSetupType = CUSTOM;     
      bCopy = FALSE ; 
      bDontCopy = TRUE ; 
      bCustom = TRUE;      
      szLicense = SUPPORTDIR^ "AbcTerms.rtf";   

Dlg_SdWelcome:
    szTitle = "";
    szMsg   = "";
    nResult = SdWelcome(szTitle, szMsg);
    if (nResult = BACK) goto Dlg_SdWelcome; 
    szTitle   = "";
    svName    = "";
    svCompany = "";   

Dlg_SdLicense:            
   nResult = SdLicense2Rtf ( "","" , "", szLicense , FALSE );    
   if(nResult = BACK) goto  Dlg_SdWelcome;

Dlg_SdCustomerInformation:
    nResult = SdCustomerInformation(szTitle, svName, svCompany, nUser);
    if (nResult = BACK) goto Dlg_SdLicense;

Dlg_SetupType:            
    szTitle = "Please select installation type"; 
    szMsg = ""; 
    szReserved  = ""; 
    svSetupType = "Viewer"; 
    nReserved   = 0;  

    nResult = SdSetupTypeEx(szTitle, szMsg, szReserved, svSetupType, nReserved);
    INSTALLTYPE =  svSetupType;   //"Console";// 

    MsiSetProperty( ISMSI_HANDLE, "DOCUSTOMEACTION" , 'copy' );

    if(svSetupType == "Console") then  

         MsiSetProperty( ISMSI_HANDLE, "INSTALLMODE" ,  "ConsoleV3");//"1:3"           
    else
         MsiSetProperty( ISMSI_HANDLE, "INSTALLMODE" , "ViewerV3" );     //"1:2"        
    endif;
    MsiSetProperty( ISMSI_HANDLE, "SOURCEPATH" , SourceDir ); 
    if (nResult = BACK) goto Dlg_SdCustomerInformation; 

Dlg_SdAskDestPath:      
    nResult = SdAskDestPath(szTitle, szMsg, INSTALLDIR, 0);
    if (nResult = BACK) goto Dlg_SetupType;     
Enable(STATUSEX);
    return 0; end;
```